# Getting WSO2 RemoteStoreManagerService api calls to work

Tags: wso2

I am trying to automate the creation of users and roles in wso2 by way of the included api's. I can list the wsdl with no problem. I can call the api authenticate with no problem. But if I call any other api endpoint such as isExistingUser I get a UserStoreException returned and a "Error occurred while accessing java Security Manager Privilege Block" in the logs. How exactly do I make an api call to check the existence of a user, add/remove a user, add/remove a role to a user?

an example of an api call that works is
https://ip address:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService/authenticate?userName=admin&credential=admin

and example of an api call that does not work is 
https://ip address:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService/isExistingUser?admin

Answer (score 1):

The request seems to be wrong. Try with parameter name as mentioned below:

https://ip address:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService/isExistingUser?**userName**=admin

Comment: yup. Managed to sort it out in the wee hours of the night. Thanks.